# A fun stochastic processes problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\textbf{X}$ be a random vector in $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^{\mathbb{N}}$ i.e. $\textbf{X}=(X_1,X_2,\cdots)$.

Consider a markov chain $\textbf{X}_0, \textbf{X}_1, \cdots$ where

$\textbf{X}_i$ - $\textbf{X}_{i-1}$ is the $m$th bit with probability $2^{-m}$.

> **Question**: What is the probability that there exists $m$ such that $\textbf{X}_m=\textbf{X}_0$?

---

Here are my ideas: Let $S = \sum\limits_{m\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(\textbf{X}_m=\textbf{X}_0)$.

Then
$$
\begin{split}
S &= \mathbb{E}[\text{ number of times chain returns to the same place}] \\
  &= 1+\sum_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{P}( \text{chain returns to the same place at least } k \text{ times}) \\
  &= \sum_{k\ge 0} \mathbb{P}( \text{chain eventually returns to the same place})^k
\end{split}
$$
If $S=\infty$ then the answer is 1. Otherwise, the answer is $1-S^{-1}$.
$$\sum_{m\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0)/m! x^m$$

---

**Proof:** Observe$$\mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0) = \sum_{i_1+i_2+\cdots = m} \prod \left( \frac{1+(-1)^{i_1}}{2}\right) \frac{m!}{\prod i_j!} \prod 2^{-ji_j}$$
Hence
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{m\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0)/m! x^m
 &= \sum_{i_1, i_2, \cdots \ge 0} \prod \left( \frac{1+(-1)^{i_1}}{2}\right) \frac{1}{\prod i_j!} \prod 2^{-ji_j} x^{i_j} \\
 &= \prod_{j\ge 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{i_j}}{2} \frac{1}{i_j!} (x2^{-j})^{i_j} \\
 &= \prod_{j\ge 1} \frac{1+(-1)^{i_j}}{2} \frac{(x2^{-j})^{i_j}}{i_j!} \\
 &= \prod_{j\ge 1} \frac 12\frac{(x2^{-j})^{i_j} + (-x2^{-j})^{i_j}}{i_j!} \\
 &= \prod_{j\ge 1} \frac 12 (\exp(x2^{-j})+\exp(-x2^{-j}))
\end{split}
$$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to ask a question.

Comment: are you asking if your solution is correct?

Comment: My question is "Find the probability that there exists m such that Xm=X0" in the 4th line. My solutions are partial and don't completely solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes: If I use $\ldots$ or $\cdots$ inappropriately, please point them out. Thanks!

Continuing from the above solution, note that $\prod_{j\ge 1} \frac 12 (\exp(x2^{-j})+\exp(-x2^{-j}))$ actually factors nicely; we can see that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=1}^n (\exp(x2^{-j})+\exp(-x2^{-j}))/2^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k \text{ odd, } 2^n > k > 2^{-n}} \exp(x2^{-n}k) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2^n (\exp(x2^{-n})-\exp(-x2^{-n}))} = \frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2x}$$
Another way to see it
Let $X_1,\cdots,$ be iid with probability distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=\frac 12$. Then this is merely the moment transform $\mathbb{E}[\exp(x(\sum_{i\ge 1} 2^{-i}X_i))]$. Since the distribution of $\sum_{i\ge 1} 2^{-i}X_i$ is $Unif(-1,1)$, the distribution of $x(\sum_{i\ge 1} 2^{-i}X_i)$ is $Unif(-x,x)$, and then we can just integrate.

Thus, if $m$ is even, $\mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0)=\frac{m!}{2} \left([x^{m+1}] \exp(x)-\exp(-x) \right)= \frac{1}{m+1}$

Now$$\sum_{m\ge 0} \mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0) =\infty$$
By Harmonic Series.

Another way to see that $\mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0)=\frac{1}{m+1}$ for $m$ even is as follows (this is my friend's solution on AoPS). Rewrite

$$\mathbb{P}(X_m=X_0) = \sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_m)\in Q_m} \left(\frac 12\right)^{k_1+\cdots+k_m}$$

I claim it is in fact equal to $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k}Y_k \right)^m \right]$$

Where $Y_k$ are iids, namely Bernoulli variables with $\mathbb{P}(Y=1)=\mathbb{P}(Y=-1)=\frac 12$

By countable linearity of expectation (when terms absolutely converge),

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k}Y_k \right)^m \right] = \sum\limits_{k_1,\cdots,k_m} 2^{-(k_1+\cdots+k_m)} \mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^m Y_{k_i}]$$

By the total independence of the $Y_j$'s, $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^m Y_{k_i}] = 1$ if each number appears an even number of times, and is 0 otherwise. Hence the conclusion follows.

As aforementioned, $$\sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k}Y_k \sim Unif(-1,1)$$

Thus, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k}Y_k \right)^m \right] = \mathbb{E}[X^m] = \frac 12 \int_{-1}^1 x^m dx = \frac{1}{m+1}$$

Where $X\sim Unif(-1,1)$.